# How to combine two Arrays that are optional

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, functional-programming

Having some trouble combining two arrays that are optional.  Not arrays that contain optional items.

```
let a : [String]? = ["foo"]
let b : [String]? = nil
```

or

```
let a : [String]? = nil
let b : [String]? = nil
```

or

```
let a : [String]? = ["foo"]
let b : [String]? = ["bar"]
```

This obviously doesn't work because the arrays are optional

```
let combinedArrays : [String]? = a + b
```

Is there a more concise way than the traditional `if let` approach using functional or some other cleaner method to combine arrays a and b?

**Update:**
The above example is contrived but below is a more real world example of what I was attempting to do:

```
func pinToAllSidesOfSuperView() -> [NSLayoutConstraint]?
{
    let horizontalConstraints : [NSLayoutConstraint]? = pinViewToLefAndRight()
    let verticalConstraints : [NSLayoutConstraint]? = pinViewToTopAndBottom()
    return horizontalConstraints + verticalConstraints
}
```

It would be nice to return an optional return value vs an empty array so the caller of the method can still use the optional features (i.e. `if let` , `guard` etc) vs the simple check if `Array.isEmpty`.

Comment: I'm unclear why you would want a constant optional. Can you show a use? Your `let combinedArrays : [String]? = a + b` isn't a reason to do it...

Comment: @Grimxn If they were declared as `var`, the question would be the same, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Grimxn - sure, the above is contrived.  I'm trying to add some autolayout extensions
`let horizontalConstraints : [NSLayoutConstraint]? = pinViewToLefAndRight()
let verticalConstraints : [NSLayoutConstraint]? = pinViewToTopAndBottom()

return horizontalConstraints + verticalConstraints`

Comment: OK, so my confusion was about what you wanted to happen when one was nil and the other not. How about `let combinedArrays : [String]? = (a ?? []) + (b ?? [])`

Comment: @Grimxn - Yeah, that would work as well.  I guess I would have to start checking `combinedArrays.count > 0` which is doable but still nil would be preferred.

Comment: Given your goals, I'd probably rethink if you even need Optionals. Why not just use `[]` in cases that you're currently using `nil`? Isn't "nothing" just as good as "None" here?

Comment: @slim update question with your clarifications/use, then it will be a really good question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is neat enough but anyway it'll give the combined string array

```
var combined = (a ?? []) + (b ?? [])
```

One of the many other options is to make it a computed property and return nil if the combined array is empty

```
var combined:[String]?{
    let c = (a ?? []) + (b ?? [])
    return c.isEmpty ? nil : c
}
```

Comment: This gives you `[]` if both arrays are `nil` instead of `nil`.

Comment: The OP has't defined what he wants to happen if either or both are nil. His clarification above suggests that would be acceptable (in which case his result should be a `[String]` and not a `[String]?`)

Answer (score 13):

I would do it like this:

```
func +<T>(lhs: Array<T>?, rhs: Array<T>?) -> Array<T>? {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {

    case (nil, nil):
        return nil

    case (nil, _):
        return rhs

    case (_, nil):
        return lhs

    default:
        return lhs! + rhs!

    }
}

let foo: [Int]? = nil
let bar: [Int]? = [1]

foo + foo   // -> nil
foo + bar   // -> [1]
bar + foo   // -> [1]
bar + bar   // -> [1, 1]
```

Comment: That's really cool, I didn't realize you could use a switch like this.

Comment: Yes, you can.  BTW, above function is a generic, define it once and you can go about similar semantics with optional arrays of any type.

Answer (score 6):

For a more functional approach, you could use `compactMap` and `flatMap` for this.

Something like following:

```swift
let a : [String]? = ["foo"]
let b : [String]? = ["bar"]

let combined = [a, b]   // create array with both optional arrays
    .compactMap({ $0 }) // remove optional from it
    .flatMap({ $0 })    // merge elements into a final array
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: this should be the correct answer, and can be applied to more complex scenarios:

Answer (score 4):

Instead of nil just make them empty arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Take one of these solutions:

1) A little bit ugly

```
let a : [String]? = ["foo"]
let b : [String]? = ["bar"]
let c = (a != nil ? a! : []) + (b != nil ? b! : []) // ["foo", "bar"]
```

2) Reload + operator for `[String]?`

```
func +(a: [String]?, b: [String]?) -> [String] {
    var s1 = a != nil ? a! : []
    let s2 = b != nil ? b! : []
    for n in s2 {
        s1.append(n)
    }
    return s1
}

let a : [String]? = ["foo"]
let b : [String]? = ["bar"]
let c : [String]? = nil
let result1 = a + b // ["foo", "bar"]
let result2 = a + c // ["foo"]
```

Btw! In overriding operator you cannot write something like:

```
func +(a: [String]?, b: [String]?) -> [String] {
    return (a != nil ? a! : []) + (b != nil ? b! : [])
}
```

As you see it will cause and infinite recursion, so I used cycle and `append()`

Comment: And why down vote? @Anton Bronnikov suggested to reload operator, as in my answer too. Can you explain, what is incorrect in my suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Ben's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59190626/242447) is correct, and can be applied to more complex scenarios as well:

```swift
let arr1: [CGFloat?] = [3, 2, nil]
let arr2: [CGFloat?]? = [4, 5, nil]

let allValues: [CGFloat] = [
    arr1.compactMap({ $0 }),
    arr2?.compactMap ({ $0 })
    ]
.compactMap({ $0 })
.flatMap({ $0 })

print(allValues) // [3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation of [0x416e746f6e's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33267016/2229783):

```
func + <T>(lhs: [T]?, rhs: [T]?) -> [T]? {
    lhs.flatMap { lhsValue in
        rhs.flatMap { rhsValue in
            lhsValue + rhsValue
        } ?? lhs
    } ?? rhs
}
```